# Background color of Git output in term mode

Tags: git, syntax-highlighting, aquamacs

I am using Aquamacs on OSX 10.9. I use the terminal mode (`M-x term`) to use Git. When I type any command, Git outputs with a different fore- and background color from the terminal. I did do a "Adopt Face and Frame parameter as Frame default" to have a unique coloring base when I initially configured Aquamacs. Right after I did it, Git started outputting with the right colors. But after closing and reopening Aquamacs, it's back to the initial difference.

What should I do? And is the "Adopt Face and Frame parameter as Frame default" the right way to setup a common base coloring for all modes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding a color theme the right way solved it.